# Filter for validating custom text addon on Woocommerce

Tags: validation, wordpress, woocommerce, hook

I am using the Woothemes Product Add-on plugin to create  an input text field on a certain product.
I need to use regular expression to validate if the text provided by customer is a valid email address. 
My problem is I don't know what filter to use to hook the validation function .
Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to run your own custom validation function on the `woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation` filter. I don't know what the name of your input is hence, I've left the input very vaguely named.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'kia_add_to_cart_validation', 10, 6);

function kia_add_to_cart_validation($add, $product_id, $product_quantity, $variation_id = '', $variations = array(), $cart_item_data = array()){
    if ( isset( $_REQUEST[ 'your-email-field' ] ) && $_REQUEST[ 'your-email-field' ] !== '' ){
        if( !is_email( trim( $_REQUEST[ 'your-email-field' ] ) ) ){
            $add = false;
            wc_add_notice( __( 'The email address you have entered is invalid' ), 'error' );
        }
    }
    return $add;
}
```